# Сбор данных из множественных полей

Tags: javascript

Нужно собрать данные пользователя в `post`, как реализовать сбор полей `email` и `phone` если они множественные?
Как собрать данные с `input`ов, если есть поля с классом `email` и поля с классом `phone` так, чтобы при повторном вызове модального окна, переменная post не хранила в себе предыдущих значений?

```
$(document).on('click', '#edituserback', function() {
var post = {};
post.uid = id;
post.ajaxRequest = true;

post.email = {};
  $('input.email').each(function(i,el){

  });

post.phone = {};
  $('input.phone').each(function(i,el){

  });
```

Comment: нужно положить их в форму и использовать метод [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Обнуляйте значения перед повторным вызовом.